# IntelliJ Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I just get started to use a `MacBook Pro Mid 2012 Release` and trying to develop with `IntelliJ`. I use `Tomcat 8` server for the deployment.

[image]

[image]

While I run the `Tomcat`, I get the following,

[image]

This 1099 comes from the `JMX port` in `Run -> Edit Configurations`. However, if I changed it to other port `(say, 1098)` doesn't help either.

I had this info as the `output`,

```
/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.15/bin/catalina.sh run
/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.15/bin/catalina.sh: line 366: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/java: No such file or directory
Disconnected from server
/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.15/bin/catalina.sh: line 366: exec: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Java related info,

```
$ which java 
/usr/bin/java

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Project `SDK` was provided `IntelliJ IDEA IU-171.4694.23`, but, tried with the `1.8` as well. No success with both of the `SDK`s.

[image]

[image]

I TOOK TO FOLLOWING STEPS SO FAR WITH NO SUCCESS,
—————————————————————————————

1. Provided the permission to run `catalina.sh`,

Initially, I didn't have the permission to run the `Tomcat` and compiled the `catalina.sh` after entering the `/bin` folder inside the `Tomcat` directory with the command,

```
$ chmod a+x catalina.sh
```

2. Appended the `hostname` in the `/etc/hosts` file,

I get the hostname from the `terminal`,

```
$ hostname
macbook-pro
```

`/etc/hosts` returns the following `(Sublime)`,

```
$ subl /etc/hosts

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost       
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost   
::1             localhost
```

Inserted the `macbook-pro` information with the localhost,

```
127.0.0.1   localhost     macbook-pro
```

3. Tried to kill the process (which I had success with `MacBook Air` earlier),

   $ ps -A | grep intellij

   $ ps -A | grep 1099

Every time get the different process info and could not `kill` the process.

What to do to solve the issue?

Update

I created a new project with the `IntelliJ` and now it runs fine with `Tomcat`. The previous project along with the `IdeaProjects` directory was imported from the other `MacBook Air` and pasted in the `base` directory. Though, I'm still unable to understand why that would be an issue.

My project is so far small (LOC < 1000 with 7 sources `.java` file). So, I'm manually creating the files and pasting the code inside from the main project. I will up for the `REAL` solution though.

Comment: What Java SDK is configured for this project?

Comment: Answered you in the original question.

Comment: All of these problems have been solved. Use spring-boot and your problems will all evaporate.

Comment: What would be the difference between the `spring-boot` and `spring-mvc`?

Comment: Does Tomcat start and work from the Terminal? Does it listen on port 1099 when started from the Terminal?

Comment: No, it doesn't start from the terminal. It does listen from the `terminal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also facing similar issue, For me the issue was related to invalid VM Options configuration in Intellij
In Intellij Click on 
Run > Edit Configuration 
Server Tab
You will notice VM Options 
My VM Options were 
-Dflyway.enabled=false -Dquratz.cron=0 0 2 1/1 * ?

When I removed -Dquratz.cron=0 0 2 1/1 * ? Intellij started the server again and the above issue was resolved , Looks like you cannot pass special characthers in VM Options

Comment: Please add some more context to your answer, i.e. what was the invalid option, etc

Comment: You the man, I moved from windows to ubuntu and had a bad var in the vm options. removing them all got me somewhere, now I just need to add the required ones back and find the bad one.

Answer (score 2):

Similar case - just because forgot to add by mistake **-D** before *VM options* configuration, i.e:

Instead of DB_USER=User should be **-D**DB_USER=User
[image]

*Foolish mistake* :)

Answer (score 2):

Check if your Tomcat contains the file `setenv.sh` (`[YOUR_CATALINA_HOME]/bin/setenv.sh`) or check `catalina.sh`; it may redefine the `CATALINA_OPTS` / `JAVA_OPTS` variable that IntelliJ uses to set up JMX. Your JMX port config (`*-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port*`) in the file (`setenv.sh` / `catalina.sh`) should be the same as in IntelliJ:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 ${CATALINA_OPTS}"
```

[image: IntelliJ Run/Debug configuration screenshot]

Comment: Originally asked about 4 years ago and this is long gone ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used `;` as separator in VM options in mac os. I added `\` to it and error disappeared:

```
-Dsome.props=prop1\;prop2\;prop3
```